# Spring boot with hdiv

Tags: spring-boot, hdiv

I am using *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE* for my MVC application.

I need to stop sensitive data exposure attack.

I have found hdiv (https://github.com/hdiv/spring-boot-starter-hdiv/blob/master/README.md )

Now if I have understood correctly, the HDIV support is available for **thymeleaf** and **jsp** only.

But I am using *angular-1.6.6.js* in the front end with HTML.

Could anyone please help me to introduce hdiv integration in my project.

Answer (score 1):

For client-mvc scenarios such as AngularJS Spring approach fits well with HDIV. Actually, HDIV has a module for that integration: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/tree/hdiv-hateoas

We can briefly define HDIV as a Java Web Application Security Framework. HDIV extends web application's behaviour by adding Security functionalities, maintaining the API and the framework specification.

HDIV Support for AngularJS; Good to refer: https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/issues/69